# Hamburger icon not showing using React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, tailwind-css, hamburger-menu

Hamburger icon is not showing on mobile but it actually does working but when I click on icon and it is not showing on mobile.

Below is my HTML:

```css
.hamburger {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 -1px 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 100
}

@media (min-width:1280px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
    margin: 18px 30px 0 0
  }
  .hamburger.active {
    display: block
  }
}

.hamburger.active span {
  background: #fff
}

.hamburger.active span:first-child {
  left: 50%;
  top: 6px;
  width: 0
}

.hamburger.active span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.hamburger.active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}

.hamburger.active span:nth-child(4) {
  left: 50%;
  top: 6px;
  width: 0
}

.hamburger span {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%
}

.hamburger span:first-child {
  top: 0
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(2),
.hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 6px
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 12px
}
```

```html
<button class="showMobileMenu inline-block bg-ubx-red text-xxl py-4 px-0 cursor-pointer outline-none focus-outline-none z-50 relative outline-none focus-outline-none text-white w-10 h-8 mobiMenuToggleIsActive xl-hidden" @click="${this._handleShowMenuClick}">
            <div className="hamburger hamburger-btn">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
          </button>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you adding empty span here? You are using reactjs for this right ?

Comment: no actually in reactjs application I am customizing this functionality

Comment: Can you share your full component ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this approach

---

```
 <button class="showMobileMenu inline-block bg-ubx-red text-xxl py-4 px-0 
  cursor-pointer outline-none focus-outline-none z-50 relative outline- 
  none focus-outline-none
```

text-white // this tailwind class is having issue, white icon is mixing with white background
w-10 h-8 mobiMenuToggleIsActive xl-
hidden" @click="${this._handleShowMenuClick}">

close

---

```
    .hamburger {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0 -1px 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none; /* Hide by default */
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
    margin: 18px 30px 0 0;
  }
  .hamburger.active {
    display: block;
  }
}

.hamburger.active span:first-child {
  left: 50%;
  top: 6px;
  width: 0;
}

.hamburger.active span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger.active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.hamburger.active span:nth-child(4) {
  left: 50%;
  top: 6px;
  width: 0;
}

.hamburger span {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.hamburger span:first-child {
  top: 0;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(2),
.hamburger span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 6px;
}

.hamburger span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 12px;
}
```

---

Try this this must work for you .

Comment: I have tried but it does not shows up hamburger icon.

Comment: Did you copy both html and css code? change class to className and then try

Comment: I have also changed to className but it does not work and after applying your html and css hamburger menu is not not even clicking previously I can click but icon was not showing.

Comment: It is working fine on my side. can you please share your whole code and react js component. Please make sure you are importing that css file correctly in your react component

Comment: can we continue this discussion on chat>?

Comment: yes ofcourse we can

Comment: can u invite for chat?

Comment: i could not find option for invitation can you do it too?

Comment: I could not find also, do u have skype?

Comment: I can share google meet link and we can discuss there after 30 minutes

Comment: Ok, yes we ca discuss there..

Comment: could u share link?

Comment: https://meet.google.com/uxx-vsyt-vwj

Comment: can you join the link so we can discuss your problem